# Visual Studio 11 launches 2 conhost.exe processes

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio, conhost

I am running Visual Studio 11 now for a while. I really like it, it has a lot of new features which makes the workdays for a (web)developer a lot easier.
[image: vs 11 about window]
But when I look at process explorer, I see several instances of `conhost.exe`. That didn't happen when I used Visual Studio 2010. Can anyone explain why there are multiple instances of `conhost` running when I use Visual Studio 11?

Comment: Not an answer, but worth the read: http://superuser.com/questions/368096/multiple-instances-of-conhost-exe

Comment: Well I have isolated that it starts at exactly the same time as visual studio 11. and I know that it is for commandline stuff. But have no idea why visual studio 11 needs it and 2010 does not.